# Giving the site design an overhaul

Tags: discussion, design, promotion

Many of the [recently](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) [graduated](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) [StackExchange](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) [sites](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) have attractive designs.

Here at Wordpress.SE, while not as plain as the [beta sites](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/), we don't have a whole lot of branding.

Knowing how easily I am attracted to the SE sites that have a great brand around them, I'm wondering whether applying some creativity here might help us attract some new users and up the level of quality SE sites foster in both questions and answers.

What do you think of proposing/requesting a redesign? If the community agrees, what is the process for doing this with SE?

I know you we'd have to apply a decent amount of creativity when we're about *code* rather than a physical object. But there are certainly ways we could allude to easily recognisable WordPress concepts (such as the loop, or common template tags like the_content()) in a stylish background image.

I'm also aware [we probably can't use the WordPress logo](http://wordpressfoundation.org/trademark-policy/) - or maybe we can, given we must've had to get permission to use WordPress in our domain name?

Either way, I'd love to know what people think of our current branding and whether doing something more would help build the community.

Comment: BTW, I like our new design. You can see the old one if you subscribe to our newsletter [which hasn't changed for some reason](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/old-design-for-newsletter). That was ugly.

Comment: The "Puzzling" site is nice. Take a look at [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) for a _really_ nice design.

Comment: Thanks @soup. I actually didn't realise it was that recent. Looking through the history I can see it's an improvement on the _old_ design, but I guess I felt it wasn't much of a design.

Comment: @kaiser Totally. I linked to both of those!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this *is* a new design. You can review the relevant history at [design](/questions/tagged/design) tag.

I would subjectively summarize situation as following — stack designs are guided more by availability, work, and vision of SE employees. It is relatively less community–driven item, than other aspects of SE network.

There is no clear workflow for community to request and/or participate in redesigns. That's about it.

I don't think it would be productive to make a ruckus about that without those circumstances evolving in some other direction.

Comment: Thanks Rarst. Looking through the history I can see it's an improvement on the old design, but I guess I felt it wasn't much of a design in itself. Your summary makes sense though.